# Avoid pressing 'done' in Meteor Facebook authentication plugin

Tags: ios, facebook, meteor, authentication

I'm building apps using Meteor. I include Facebook authentication through the accounts-facebook package.

When running my apps as a web-app, logging in through Facebook works nicely. When deploying as an iOS app, the Facebook login works, but, at the end of authentication, the user is presented with an almost completely blank screen, with, at the bottom, the app URL (hosted at Modulus) used for authentication, and a 'Done' link in the bottom left.

The 'Done' link needs to be clicked to continue.

Obviously, this is not user friendly. How can the Facebook login be streamlined such that pressing the 'Done' link is not necessary, or that the 'Done' button is very prominently displayed, when running the Meteor app on iOS?

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Any progress with that? I have the same problem.

Comment: No. For unknown reasons, it now happens to me intermittently, not all the time. Consider voting the question up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by including an modified version of cordova-plugin-inappbrowser based on [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6882).

You can add as follow:

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@https://github.com/ephemer/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git#04091fde737519c149e7ad6316971cb6b490c5b3
```

The thing is that the version of inappbrowser used by Meteor doesn't fully handle the close() function.